# iTunes shows App Updates Badge, but no updates are available

Tags: itunes, applications, upgrade

On my iTunes page, it is showing a 7 next to Apps to indicate I have 7 apps with available updates.  When I click on the link to show available updates, regardless of which iTunes account I have, it always shows "No Updates are available".  How can I see what apps it thinks I have updates for, or reset that counter?

Comment: Are you using the same iTunes account you used to download the applications?

Comment: I have 3 itunes accounts, and I have logged in as each one, checked for updates and still there are no updates available but the badge still shows 7.

Comment: Is there a way we would be able to find out which one of the apps needs updating when such a thing occurs?

Answer (score 3):

The common cause of this is when you have purchases in one library that belong to two Apple ID's. You will have to sign in to that second Apple ID to download those updates. This means iTunes is working as it was designed (although it is confusing since the Apple ID for each purchase is "hidden" in the info and not easily displayed.

A less common instance is when there is a problem with either the on line store or your local files that store the apps.

Here are two articles that will help if you simply have more than one account making purchases:

- [Which account did I use to make a specific purchase?](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2427370)
- [iOS: Changing the signed-in iTunes Store account](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1311)

Comment: I have checked all my apps and every app is either one of my 3 itunes accounts.  Thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: Bummer - you might have to wait for someone to answer how to troubleshoot problems with the Apple ID or the iTunes app. Have you tried asking Apple online for support? Anything that makes me less likely to spend money on the store always gets their attention to help me resolve/understand the issue whether I'm in warranty or not.

Answer (score 2):

Another cause for iTunes to do this is when you purchased an app in one country's store and you changed it to another country. [That's what happened to me](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17756/do-i-need-to-repurchase-apps-if-i-moved-countries).

Updates are only available from the AppStore country you bought the app in (but the badge may still be displayed).

Comment: Any way to solve it?

Comment: Change the store country in you iTunes Account settings, as there is no way to migrate purchases done in one country to a different one.

Answer (score 1):

Another cause for iTunes to do this is when you purchased an app in one country's store and you changed it to another country. That's what happened to me.

Updates are only available from the AppStore country you bought the app in (but the badge may still be displayed).

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me, my wife and I use separate **computer** accounts but they both use the same iTunes store ID. Occasionally I would have to go into my wife's computer account and run the app update in iTunes there to get rid of the badge in iTunes under my computer account.