# How can I re-download all the apps I bought on another store account?

Tags: itunes, ios-appstore

I have moved to another country, which comes along with the joy of moving apple store accounts. This would be easier, however, if there were a trivial automated way to re-download all of my free apps under the new ID.

Before going any further, I *know* that I'll have to re-purchase any in-app purchases, and that no process is going to get me my apps back free. It sucks, but there it is.

I've written a small tool to list each app in my library and identify it by owner, price, and store URL. The thing is, I want to take the one extra step: Re-purchase the app from the store, under the new account, and replace the old one. Right now, this process is painfully manual:

1. Delete the existing app
2. Open the store URL in my browser. This opens iTunes to the app
3. Buy the app
4. *repeat ad nauseam*

I've got almost 150 apps to do this with. It'll take forever.

Is there an easier way to bulk delete/redownload apps in iTunes?

Answer (score 1):

Check my story:

[Do I need to repurchase apps if I moved countries?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17756/do-i-need-to-repurchase-apps-if-i-moved-countries)

In short - you can't. You have to stick to your old account for updates of the software you bought and create a new AppleID for purchases in new country.

Unless of course you are willing to pay for all applications (and in-app purchases) again. Then there's no need to have another AppleID, you just switch store country, but there's no automation for re-buying them unfortunately.

Comment: This is also not addressing the question. I KNOW I can't get them moved for free. I'm asking about ways to automate  reacquiring the free ones.

Comment: I stated in the last sentence that there's no automation for this unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

No solution for a new account. But you don't need to use a new Apple account, you can just sign in on your old Apple ID. That way all your existing apps are already authorised and you don't have to re-download them.
Or if you've already deleted them, they will show up as purchased.

Comment: I'm well aware that I can _use_ them. That's clearly not what I'm asking. The apps work, but I'm sick of the sign-out-update-sign-in-verify-payment-instruments-navigate-back-to-the-new-store-update-the-rest cycle.