# How do I change the account of the App Store on iPad to another account?

Tags: ipad, ios-appstore, ipados

1. I used an account in Taiwan before the Covid-19 situation two years ago
2. I used a Debit Card with about TW$3000 (about US$100) in it
3. But during these two years I have used up the TW$3000. (I am in the US now)
4. Now when I try to upgrade Garage Band, it says, "Your last payment had issue", and I already went through the process to remove that Debit Card.
5. But now, it says "Your last payment had issue" and then I typed in password, and then it brings me back to the Taiwan payment tab, and I  tapped Done, and
6. it asked me to authenticate using 2-Form Factor authentication, and then it brings me back to Step 5 again
7. I have already changed in Settings, my media and purchase to a different account, which is a US account
8. However, it is still stuck in that infinite loop of Step 5 and Step 6
9. I have rebooted the iPad at least 3, 4 times, hoping it will now use the US account, but there is no use

So instead of insanely great, it has changed to insanely stupid.  How can this be solved?  I am not even making a purchase. I am merely updating Garage Band.

Comment: Are you in possession of both accounts? Typically people will [leave the old account in the old country](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/22376/5472) if moving it blocks downloads. There’s no good solution, as stringing along multiple accounts for each country is a hassle as is losing past purchases not available in the new geo. Hopefully you just need Apple support to tell you what’s wrong with the account you try to update garage band.

Comment: Yup, both accounts belong to me. For at least 10 years, users have been able to buy and view media independently with both accounts and switch to an account once per every 3 months per device.  For this iPad, I have used it for 10 months with this Taiwan account without ever switching.