# I want to change the country on my app store account and I am having some problems?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipod, ios-appstore, itunes-store

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do I need to repurchase apps if I moved countries?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17756/do-i-need-to-repurchase-apps-if-i-moved-countries)

So I wanted to change the country on my app store account but I was told that all of the purchases made in that region will be blocked and won't work so I wanted to make a new app store account but I need to know if I won't get all of my other apps blocked when I log into this account or when I create it. So lets call my current country on the account A and what I want to change it to is B. If I made a new account and logged into the account for country B, will it be the appstore of that country? And if so then when I want to log back to my account on country A will I be able to do it just by signing out and then in again?

Comment: This question is in effect a duplicate of [Do I need to repurchase apps if I moved countries?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/17756/11791).

Answer (score 0):

First you create an account for country B (the easiest way to do this is to create the account in the iTunes Store on your computer). Then when you log in to the account for country B, you will be redirected to the App Store of country B. While you're logged in to the account for country B you will still be able to use apps, music, books, etc. you purchased with the account for country A. When you want to go back to the App Store or iTunes Store of country A, you just need to log out en log in again with your account for country A.

So the short answers to you questions are:

- Yes.
- Yes.