# Why are past purchases no longer showing after I change country of my Apple ID?

Tags: applications, mac-appstore, ios-appstore, apple-id, itunes-store

Recently I've changed the country in my Apple ID account. While everything else is fine there's an issue with my purchases. All Apps that were purchased before the change don't appear in Purchased section of App Store and in the list of available updates as well. However the updates count budge in iTunes shows a dozens of updates available but after being pressed there are only apps purchased after the change had been made in the list.

I tried to delete the apps from library and re-purchase them but with no success. I got them for free as I should but the problem hasn't gone.
Is there any solution?

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/86349/re-downloading-apps-purchased-in-a-different-country/116715#116715

Comment: Actually better to see the other answer there, @lhunath http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/105804/1174

Comment: Seems that this problem has been fixed now

Answer (score 5):

This is by design.

A developer lists an app for one or more markets and when you lose past purchases, that indicates that that app was available in the old market and no longer is available in the new market.

Have a look on the site, there are several threads on people deciding to switch countries or keep an old account.

One is simpler and potentially costs more, the other costs more time, but you keep access to all purchases, past, present and future on two accounts.

- [I want to change the country on my app store account and I am having some problems?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/38616/i-want-to-change-the-country-on-my-app-store-account-and-i-am-having-some-proble?rq=1)
- [Restoring past purchases from different country](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/80528/restoring-past-purchases-from-different-country?rq=1)
- [Do I need to repurchase apps if I moved countries?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17756/do-i-need-to-repurchase-apps-if-i-moved-countries?rq=1)

Also - the related section to the right should have several more likely threads to help.

Comment: I don't think that the 'market question' is much important here. Yes, some developers are targeting their specific apps to certain market when it makes sense but most of them go as many markets as they can widening the crowd of potential buyers/users. For instance it'd be quite silly for Google not to go even the one more market available for expansion with their Chrome. In my case ALL APPS purchased before the switch are not in the list.

Comment: Hmm - I may have missed something, but if you still have old apps installed and there is an update, you will get an update badge. Without knowledge of a specific app, I can't be sure. Have you opened a ticket with Apple's store billing staff to investigate one or two apps in question?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, here's what I have learnt about purchases in iTunes App store after Apple ID's country switch by now (from my own experience (same ID, different country - Russia to USA)):

1. You won't lose any app you purchased before the switch, but
2. You won't have any of them in your 'purchased' list wherever you check it (iTunes, iOS,...),
3. You'll be able to update any of them for free:
   (a) manually redownloading it in iTunes, as soon as you know the update have        happen (it will only pop up with something like 'You've purchased it before and now it's free');
   (b) updating normally from within App Store App on any iOS device where the app in question is installed.

(Just a wee tip: you can load an App like AppShopper with information about Apps you have and it will give you notification every time it's been updated)

Hopefully it will help someone