# How to download bought apps without old credit card?

Tags: mac-appstore, apple-id

I changed my residence and cancel my old credit card. Now I did a clean install of OS X and want to download purchased apps and free apps (Aperture, Keynote and iPhoto) but the App Store asks me for my credit card info and since I don't have it anymore I can't do it.

What can I do? How to change my credit card info to that where I'm living now? Will that respect my purchased apps?

Comment: Switching credit cards shouldn't invalidate old purchases

Comment: The thing is I have a new credit card from where I'm living now, however the purchases where made with a credit card from my old country of residence

Comment: Ah, you moved from one country to another?

Comment: Yes I did. I canceled the credit card from the country I was living in but now I have a new credit card of my new country.

Comment: So you are basically are in the same situation as described in http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/86349/re-downloading-apps-purchased-in-a-different-country?rq=1 ?

Comment: Yes, however they suggest to have two Apple IDs which I don't want to do (and it is the accepted answer). There is another answer that says that changing country and downloading already purchased apps will incur no charge, however I don't know how true is this.

Comment: "Accepted" just means that the asker found it most helpful, it doesn't imply correctness. Maybe contacting Apple Support might be the better option in your case (as also mentioned in one of the answers).

Comment: If you use same Apple ID as before and not purchasing new stuff, the Card will not be used and it is not relevant in this case.

Comment: When I try to update my credit card info, in the app store for Switzerland (which is where I was living) there is no "none" option for payment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you purchased an app, you can always re-download that app free of charge, given that the following criteria are true:

- The app is still offered on the App Store
- The app is available in your country

If you moved countries and all the above is true for you, apps purchased elsewhere will be hidden, but can still be obtained by regularly searching for them.

They will state a price and you will need to go through the purchase process again, but once you entered the Apple ID you used to purchase the app originally, you WILL receive a message saying that you already own it and that the download will be free of charge.

I know that this sounds scary and I always shiver until I receive that message myself, but having moved countries myself, I can confirm that behavior and never had any problems re-downloading an app (except for sometimes finding them among the many other search results when looking for it).

One thing, however, since you mentioned Aperture and iPhoto.  Since Apple is discontinuing those apps, if you want to keep them, re-download them very soon and make a copy (e.g. compress them) to store somewhere on your computer.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Just two more doubts 1. Will this apply for music too? 2. Can you point me to a website where it explains how to change countries?

Comment: I have not tried it with Music myself to be honest and given that they are DRM-free I am not entirely sure.  For that specific category, I would contact the iTunes Store support and ask.  You can initiate this from this link: http://www.apple.com/support/itunes/contact.  The official guide to change countries can be found here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201389.  In case it does not let you change countries, follow the link at the end of that article.