# Can a single Apple ID/ iTunes account switch between multiple country AppStores to buy free Apps unique to each country?

Tags: ios-appstore, apple-id, itunes-store

Can a single Apple ID/ iTunes account switch between multiple country AppStores to buy free Apps unique to each country?

If I use my single Apple ID/ iTunes account but move & have moved across countries where certain Apps are only on those country AppStores, can I switch between them and buy Free Apps, yet maintain them on my iTunes and iOS devices?

Additional Information:
I am wondering if this [workaround](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/116715/38176) worked for someone / still works?

It was done on Mac OSX, but I am wondering if it can be done in Windows.

Comment: Please check: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/86349/re-downloading-apps-purchased-in-a-different-country

Answer (score 1):

Changing a country of your single Apple ID is a pain. You can do it ones without consequences but the second time you do it you'll be asked to provide credit card details of a "new" country of your residence. The easiest way to use App Store of different countries is to have 2 different Apple ID registered for certain country.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, but you'll want to follow the steps in this guide (https://support.apple.com/en-ph/HT201389) since switching countries back and forth can produce migraines if not done properly. Especially if you have any paid apps or apps that have been removed from the App Store, but you still own.