# Restoring past purchases from different country

Tags: itunes, mac-appstore, ios-appstore, apple-id

I recently moved countries, and have purchases associated on my iTunes account.

Once I moved countries, I changed the country on my Apple ID to my new country.

However, after using a store card on my account, I can't change my account back to my previous country and access my past purchases, because I still have store credit on my account, which I can't spend.

I've contacted Apple about removing my store credit, but will I be able to access my past purchases once I actually change my country back?

I've just reinstalled my Mac, and need to re-download iPhoto, iMovie and GarageBand.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: This hasn't worked so well on the iOS store, so I don't have a good feeling about it on the Mac App store either. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17756/do-i-need-to-repurchase-apps-if-i-moved-countries

Comment: How did you change a country while having store credit?
Did Apple remove the credit and refunded you in some way?

Comment: It wasn't enough money to worry about, they just deleted it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple contacted me back, I changed my country, and all my purchases have been restored.

Comment: May I ask how did you got them to contact you back? How did contact them in the first place?