# Cancel Apple Music before period finishes

Tags: apple-music

I am trying to change my iTunes store region, and to do so requires me to cancel my Apple Music subscription. So I cancelled it, and it says "will expire on 15th January". When I now try and change the region, it still says I need to cancel my subscription.

Can I kill my subscription before the last billed month finishes?

Comment: Please read the answers to http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17756/do-i-need-to-repurchase-apps-if-i-moved-countries/239802#239802 before switching the country of your iTunes account. It might be easier to create a new account for the new country.